# Determination of a distribution problem.

Tags: statistics

Would love to get some advice concerning a dilemma I'm having with an exercise.

There's a basket with $W $ white balls and $B$ black balls. A ball is randomly taken out 3 times.

Everytime the ball is returned with an addition of $C$ balls of the same color.

Defining a group of discrete random variables $X_i$ ($i$ from 1 to 3), each random variable get's a-0 if a black ball is drawn or 1 if a white ball is drawn.

For example,
if a white ball was drawn the first time then $X_1=$1,

and if a black ball was drawn the second time then $X_2=0$,
and if a white ball was drawn the third time then $X_3=1$.

It sounds to me like the total amount of white balls drawn during the 3 attempts is a binomial distribution, BUT when I check if the random variables are dependent then the condition

$P(X1=1 ∩ X2=1)=P(X1=1)*P(X2=1)$

is false because I get
$W (W+C)/((B+W)*(B+W+C))=W * W/((W+B)(W+B))$
which is false.

Am I not checking correctly whether the variables are dependant, or is the total amount of white balls drawn actually not a binomial distribution?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Of course the variables are dependent.  If the first drawn is white then there will be more white balls in the urn afterwards.  But, you only have three trials.  Just write out all the possible cases.

Comment: I agree but consider that P(x1=1)=P(x2=1)=W/(W+B) when you take into account all possibilities, which makes me think twice.

Comment: alse I computed the mean of the number of white balls to be 3W/(W+B) which suites the formula for the mean of a binomial function.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a binomial distribution in this context.  Which variable do you believe has a binomial distribution?  how have you handled the obvious dependence between the variables that appear in your post?

Comment: Just to stress the dependence:  say $W=B=1$ and that $C=10^{100}$.  Then we are effectively certain that $x_2=x_1$, yes?  Whatever you pick first, you are almost certainly going to choose second.

Comment: I believe that the total amount of white balls taken out in all trials might be a binomial variable, because that the probability of each variable(X1=1,X2=1,X3=1) is W/(W+B) when you take into account all possibilities. So I'm thinking maybe they're not dependent after all.

Comment: Why do you persist in believing that $P(X_1 = 1) = P(X_2 = 1) = P(X_3 = 1)$? This is very obviously not true. The problem clearly states that after the first draw either the number of whites or the number of blacks changes. This changes the probability of getting a white on the second draw. In fact, $$P(X_2 = 1) = \dfrac{P(X_1 = 0)W + P(X_1 = 1)(W + C)}{W + B +C}$$

Comment: Becaus P(X1=0)=B/(W+B) and P(X1=1)=W/(W+B), when you calculate the expression that you wrote you finally get P(X2=1)=W/(W+B), and the same applies for P(X3=1).